# Changing DNS Server - how to update Static assigned Member servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

We are upgrading our Server from 2008 to 2012. In that process, We have a Windows Server 2012 acting as a new DNS, with a new IP - DNS2.

Most of our servers use static IP (as well as DNS assignment) and pointing to the old DNS (DNS1)

What is the correct way to update the DNS1 IP - to the new DNS2 IP? but still keep the static settings on the member servers?

Do I need to go over each server manually?

Comment: `Most of our servers use static IP` - I would hope that they all do. `Do I need to go over each server manually?` - That's one way to do it and seems like the most direct method to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and netsh to remote change the DNS servers

use `netsh interface show interface` to show the interfaces

use `netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "InterfaceFromAbove" address=DNSIP index=1` to set the DNS server

It would be easy if they all have the same interface name

Comment: Does this *add* a DNS server, or *update* the first server as requested by the OP? If, as I suspect, this doesn't remove the defunct IP, including those steps would make this a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a lot of servers such that it would be worth the effort to write a script to update them, the best approach is to update the DNS settings by hand. You *can* do it other ways, but there's a time trade-off to consider.